# ¿Como convertir una variable php string obtenida de una var Javascript a int/integer?

Tags: php, javascript

estoy intentando cambiar el valor string de una cadena javascript a integer.
Me explico: Tengo una variable PHP **$longitud** y una variable Javascript **var arrayValoresSubcategoria**...

`<?php $longitud = (int) "<script>document.write(arrayValoresSubcategoria.length);</script>"
var_dump($longitud);?>`

Lo que arroja es int(0) en mi intento de convertirlo a integer, porque tal parece que lee la cadena completa `"<script>...</script>"` que son unos 70 caracteres pero al convertirlo a integer esa demasiada su longitud.
¿tienen alguna idea de como convertirlo a int/integer?

Comment: Del lado del servidor cuando haces var_dump, el código JS aún no ejecuta por lo que esta variable permanece vacía, y cuando está del lado del cliente, esa variable ya no existe porque ya fue procesada por el servidor. Tienes que leer Ajax, que es lo que ocupas para poder resolver el problema que tienes.

Comment: Pero si lo imprime, cuando hago var_dump($longitud), sale string "75" (20)
OJO sale string si le quito la conversión (int) al principio de la cadena `<script>...</script>`

Comment: Normalmente php hace ese trabajo por tí, si por ejemplo a esa variable le sumas cualquier número, te regresará la suma de el resultado y no la concatenación como ocurriría en JS normalmente

Comment: Revisa la documentacion de php para conversion de cadenas a numeros en php   http://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Comment: Como dice @Lixus, no puedes pasar una variable de JS a PHP así por así. JS está del lado del cliente y PHP se ejecuta en el servidor. Tendrías que buscar una forma de enviar esa variable y luego leerla en el servidor, (generalmente mediante `GET` o `POST`). Lee por ejemplo [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1917626/5587982).

Comment: el problema es que no estas asignando el numero js a la variable php. Estas asignando "la cadena de javascript", cuando haces el var_dump, php imprime el código javascript y el navegador lo transforma en el numero... se entiende? No puedes hacerlo asi, no va a funcionar. No se que quieres conseguir, pero si es pasar esta variable al sservidor, lo mejor es usar un form o ajax